# Support to read images via OPC UA with eclipse milo

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I just found in the OPCUA specification that images are supported (BMP, GIF, JPG and PNG) (see [link](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/DI/v102/docs/5.5.5/)). I also went through the `org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Identifiers` and I see that types exist to handle those image formats:

```
    public static final NodeId ImageBMP = init(2000);
    public static final NodeId ImageGIF = init(2001);
    public static final NodeId ImageJPG = init(2002);
    public static final NodeId ImagePNG = init(2003);
```

The question is, has milo currently support for reading those image formats via OPCUA? Any example of how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just read the Value attribute like any other VariableNode.

The result will be a ByteString. Those NodeIds you found are the ids of alias/simple DataTypes that inherit from ByteString and serve as a hint to what the contents of the ByteString will be.

It’s up to you to turn the bytes into an image after that - it doesn’t have anything to do with OPC UA or Milo at that point. You’ll probably want to look at the [ImageIO API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html).